# PDF Define an area and delete everything outside it with a Script

Tags: python, xml, pdf, svg, pymupdf

I'm trying to define an area in a pdf and delete everything around it. I tried with the Python Library PyMuPDF without too much success.
With this library I can define a crop zone and 'hide' everything around it but my problem is that after doing this I have to transform my pdf into an svg and in this svg all the 'hide' elements are still present.

To give an exemple:

There is my original pdf file : [Input PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUk27.png)

Google drive link to the pdf : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tNVtTM3BDcbJAhRtrUsSM0JvwZnFTa-y/view?usp=sharing

That's my Python Script to crop it :

```
import fitz
import svgutils

doc = fitz.open("exemple.pdf")

page = doc[0]

page.clean_contents()

# Define the redaction margins (left, top, right, bottom)
margin = (33, 33, 33, 33)

# Get the number of pages in the PDF
num_pages = len(doc)

for page_number in range(num_pages): 
    
    page = doc[page_number]

    # Define the cropbox
    cropbox = (margin[0], margin[3], page.rect.width - margin[2], page.rect.height - margin[1])

    page.set_cropbox(fitz.Rect(cropbox))

    page.clean_contents()

    # Retrieve the SVG
    svg = page.get_svg_image()
    

# SVG Name
nom_fichier = "test_exemple.svg"

# SVG in W mode
with open(nom_fichier, "w") as fichier:
    # Write the svg content in the file
    fichier.write(svg)

svg = svgutils.transform.fromfile("test_exemple.svg")
originalSVG = svgutils.compose.SVG("test_exemple.svg")

# originalSVG.scale(240/306)

#figure = svgutils.compose.Figure(240, 153, originalSVG)

#figure.save('svgResized.svg')

# Print Succes
print(f"The content was well copied {nom_fichier}")
```

My SVG output : [Output SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwCoU.png)

Visually I'm good, but on the programming side the corner lines are still present for exemple this SVG in a 3D Software like blender [Output SVG in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvm4A.png)

I've been stuck for a while and I can't find a way to remove content from a pdf using a script, if you have any ideas on how to do this, I'd love to hear from you.

Thanks.

Comment: Using PyMuPDF, you can remove text, images and links physically using redaction annotations. Unfortunately, this is not possible for vector graphics as in your case.
But there **_may_** be a way to hack the page's appearance command stream and identify and "edit away" the pesky draw commands. Let me try your example PDF. It is however a PNG!

Comment: Yes, after searching the documentation, I couldn't find anything about this. I was thinking that maybe I could redissine the graphics vectors, and ignoring the corner lines, but it was very complicated, and it would work for this pdf, but to automate the task, it seems complicated to me.I haven't found a library capable of doing that.
Ok thanks you!

Comment: I've added a google drive link to download the pdf

Comment: Yes, I know, if I could use Adobe Illustrator directly it would be very simple, but I'd like to do this operation with a script and I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: It was just an example, for my problem I'll always have the same document format, they'll all be the same size, so once I know where the crop lines are, I can apply a crop always at the same x,y position.

Comment: All right, I'll try it with Artifex Ghostscript!

Comment: Damn, it was that simple...I've been trying for a week to make scripts in every possible language to delete this box from a pdf... thanks you very much!